# Cannot append a select box with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Start with: I am very new to Front End dev (it got added to my java backend work:)). I have a modal that opens on a page with a table with two rows - each with 2 inputs and a select box. If  you click a button....it should add another row with the same elements. They use to do it this way: have a table footer that was hidden with the elements in (starting with row: <tr>), then when you click the button it calls the table body and .append the footer. Then call the attr on the three elements and change the id and name. For some reason if the footer is unhidden...the dropdown works, but the copied version doesn't. We investigated the names, the values, etc. The values are in the rendered html...the dropdown just doesn't open.

So now what I am trying to do...which I feel might be cleaner. Is create a variable with the html...and append that everytime the button is clicked. But the select element has a tag that was written...so I don't know if this is the problem, but everytime I try and add it to the mix....There are errors about unexpected token(<). If I take the one line that starts <dfm:catombobox> away - it works... Anyone have ideas to help me add the "catombobox" which is the select with the tag? PS: If I take the quotes away and just copy that line to the original table...it works??

```
 var newRow = '<tr>'+
              '<td nowrap="nowrap"><strong>R</strong> <input class="amount input-small" style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0;" type="text"/></td>'+
              '<td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-top: 7px;">'+

              '<dfm:catombobox cssClass="input-medium" id="CategoryId_Test" name="CategoryName_Test" showEmptyCategory="true" showGroups="true" value=""/>'+

               '</td>'+
               '<td><input class="input-medium" style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0;" type="text"/></td>'+
               '<td><a class="remove" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>'+
               '</tr>';
            $("#mytable tbody").append(newRow);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using [select](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) instead of dfm:catombobox

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the data in the select box is a bit complex. It comes in different levels and the tag was not only designed with company styling standards in mind, but also takes care of putting the right options and groups in the drop down. I tested the exact line of code in my html and it works. So it seems like the problem is how to make the variable or the "apped" recognise that this should be handled in the same way as the hmtl page would have?

Comment: Then in that case simply use : $("#mytable tbody").append(newRow); by binding it to a buttons click event

Answer (score 0):

check here its working fine

[adding new rows to table](http://jsfiddle.net/Faheem66/XMBZk/1/)

```
var newRow = '<tr>' +
    '<td nowrap="nowrap"><strong>R</strong> <input class="amount input-small" style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0;" type="text"/></td>' +
    '<td nowrap="nowrap" style="padding-top: 7px;">' +

    '<dfm:catombobox cssClass="input-medium" id="CategoryId_Test" name="CategoryName_Test" showEmptyCategory="true" showGroups="true" value=""/>' +

    '</td>' +
    '<td><input class="input-medium" style="margin-top: 8px;margin-bottom: 0;" type="text"/></td>' +
    '<td><a class="remove" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></td>' +
    '</tr>';
$("#btn").on('click',function(){
    $("#mytable tbody").append(newRow);
})
```

Comment: So currently the variable declaration as well as the append is in the click function:  $("#add").click(function() {......}). Should I have the variable global then and only append in this function? Does it make a difference?

Comment: Okay -I only now managed to open your example. If you look at my table row...there are three columns. Column 1 and 3 have inputs. Column 2 is the dropdown. Your example is also not showing the select box?

Comment: Yes this is working, but this is the same as me taking my &lt;dfm:catombobox&gt; line out. So it works with straight html elements...but for some reason it is not recognising what to do with that custom tag. So I need to find out how to get it to recognise this when it appends :(